# Tons of error in Visual Studio 2017 with GetUserNameEx at compile time

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to use GetUserNameEx, but cannot even compile it because I got tons of errors. This is my code:

```
   #include <Windows.h>
    #include <Secext.h>
    #include <tchar.h>
    #include <wchar.h>

    #pragma comment(lib, "Secur32.lib")

    int wmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv[])
    {

        //GetUserNameEx()
        EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT nameFormat = NameDnsDomain;
        WCHAR nameExtended[256 + 1];
        DWORD sizeExtended = 256 + 1;


        if (GetUserNameEx(nameExtended, &sizeExtended))
        {

            wprintf(L"%s\n", nameExtended);
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf(L"Error code: %lu\n", GetLastError());
        }
return 0;
}
```

These are the errors I am getting when trying to compile:

[image: Errors from Visual Studio 2017]

Can you help me? Seems like the compiler could not recognize that function.

Edit: I cannot include all the errors because there are around 48 has nothing to do with the code, except for the wrong function calling.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the error(s) in the question itself.

Comment: Didn't want to write around 48 errors. As you can see in the answers, there is an issue with the definitions.

Comment: Don't show the IntelliSense errors. The only interesting errors are build errors. Post them, as text. Future visitors looking for help cannot find this Q&A, because images cannot readily be searched. Text can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are including the wrong header. The documentation usually contains two pieces of information regarding headers: The header file that declares a symbol, as well as the header file you are supposed to `#include`.

From the [Requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724435.aspx) section:

> **Header:** Secext.h (include Security.h)

To solve the issue, replace

```
#include <Secext.h>
```

with

```
#include <Security.h>
```

It is important to always include the header file you are told to. Header files often change the environment, and when you try to include the header that declares a symbol directly, all sorts of odd things can happen.

You also have a bug in your call, passing the wrong arguments. It should be this instead:

```
    WCHAR nameExtended[256 + 1];
    ULONG sizeExtended = 256 + 1;

    if (GetUserNameExW(NameDnsDomain, nameExtended, &sizeExtended)) {
        // ...
```

Compiling this produces the following error:

> ```
> fatal error C1189: #error:   You must define one of SECURITY_WIN32, SECURITY_KERNEL, or
> ```

(The trailing `SECURITY_MAC` is missing, due to wrong formatting in a system header.)

To fix this, `#define` the preprocessor symbol `SECURITY_WIN32` (for user-mode applications<sup>1</sup>) prior to including *<Security.h>*, either in code or through the project settings, e.g.:

```
#define SECURITY_WIN32
#include <Security.h>
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *There is very little information regarding those preprocessor symbols. The most enlightening comment is from* <NTSecPKG.h> *reading `// Can't use the windows.h def'ns in kernel mode.` inside an `#ifdef SECURITY_KERNEL` conditional. `SECURITY_MAC` is likely from those days, when MFC was still meant to be a cross-platform framework, targeting Windows as well as "Classic" Mac OS. It is of no practical use today.*

Comment: #define SECURITY_WIN32 fixed the errors for me (for a user mode app). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

1. There seems to be a define issue regarding `SEC_ENTRY`.  <s>I believe it's meant to defined as `__stdcall`.  I'm still researching this.</s>  It's actually resolved by including `<sspi.h`> first and defining a security model.
2. Regardless, the call to GetUserNameEx is incorrect.

Instead of this:

```
if (GetUserNameEx(nameExtended, &sizeExtended))
```

It should be this:

```
if (GetUserNameEx(nameFormat, nameExtended, &sizeExtended))
```

Adjusted code:

```
#define SECURITY_WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#include <sspi.h>
#include <secext.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Secur32.lib")

int wmain(int argc, WCHAR *argv[])
{

    //GetUserNameEx()
    EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT nameFormat = NameDnsDomain;
    WCHAR nameExtended[256 + 1] = {};
    DWORD sizeExtended = ARRAYSIZE(nameExtended);

    if (GetUserNameEx(nameFormat, nameExtended, &sizeExtended))
    {
        wprintf(L"%s\n", nameExtended);
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"Error code: %lu\n", GetLastError());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would the person who downvoted this answer care to explain his dislike?

Comment: Maybe because you propose to include the wrong header? I would personally dislike actively ignoring the documentation.